# GitHub TypeScript Evaluator - Error: Process completed with exit code 1

Tags: javascript, typescript, github

I am trying to push a project but the GitHub evaluator keeps crashing with the error bellow.

I have the NPM package even though it says I do not.

This is the backend part of the project. I installed many dependencies such as bcriptjs and joi, and theoricaly it shouldn't ask everything in the packages.npm if I already have then in the dev dependency.

```
    Step 5/7 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in ab9898636e49
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  
npm WARN deprecated formidable@1.2.6: Please upgrade to latest, formidable@v2 or formidable@v3! 
npm WARN deprecated superagent@3.8.3: Please upgrade to v7.0.2+ of superagent.  We have fixed numerous issues with streams, form-data, attach(), filesystem errors not bubbling up (ENOENT on attach()), and all tests are now passing.  See the releases tab for more information at...
npm WARN deprecated @types/chai-http@4.2.0: This is a stub types definition. chai-http provides its own type definitions, so you do not need this installed.

> tfc-backend@1.0.0 postinstall
> if [ ! -z 'cat ./packages.npm' ]; then npm i --ignore-scripts $(cat ./packages.npm); fi

cat: can't open './packages.npm': No such file or directory

[...]

Step 6/7 : COPY . .
 ---> 5011bb350630
Step 7/7 : CMD ["npm", "start"]
 ---> Running in 49d6a4e7c964
Removing intermediate container 49d6a4e7c964
 ---> 1a039ac02843
Successfully built 1a039ac02843
Successfully tagged app_frontend:latest
Creating db ... 
Creating db ... done
Creating app_backend_1 ... 
Creating app_backend_1 ... done

ERROR: for frontend  Container "f8ea808f77e7" is unhealthy.
Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
+ '[' 1 '!=' 0 ']'
+ echo 'Compose execution error'
+ exit 1
Compose execution error
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: I've never heard of a `packages.npm` file. Did you mean `package.json`? Otherwise, please add some more detail to your question. What is the "GitHub TypeScript Evaluator" exactly? Do you get this error when you run those commands locally? Is the `cat ./packages.npm` from your run script or some dependency? Please add this and more to your question.

Comment: No, package.npm, that's it. Actually I solved the problem. It was an issue with the way I was initializing the docker file.  I was trying to start on both server.ts and app.ts, and I did not add joi
@types/joi to the packages.npm file. Thanks!